# Flex mobile - How do I move to the next data in List.selectedItem when moving to next page?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flexbuilder, flex4.5

When I move page01 to page02, I pass the same data along with it using the following code:

```
navigator.pushView(Page02, data);
```

How do I move to page02 with passing the next row of data (instead of the same data)? 
In other word, how to increment to the next row of data with pushView?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need some access to the data structure; and the current "index" That is being displayed / process.

Comment: ok, i get the selectedIndex but how to push the data to the next page?
i try using the following code but it won't work.

    `navigator.pushView(page02, myList.selectedIndex + 1);` i can only use **selectedItem**

Comment: If you have access to the list (I assume a UIComponent) do something like this: myList.dataProvider[myList.selectedIndex+1] .  I'll post that as a real answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the List component which displays the data you want to pass into views, you can do something like this:

```
myList.dataProvider[myList.selectedIndex+1]
```

You'll want to do some checking to make sure that you're trying to reference an index that actually exists:

```
var mySelectedObject :Object;
if(myList.selectedIndex+1 < myList.dataProvider.length){
    mySelectedObject = myList.dataProvider[myList.selectedIndex+1] 
} else {
    // do some other behaviour; such as selecting the first one in the list
    mySelectedObject = myList.dataProvider[0] 
}
navigator.pushView(page02, mySelectedObject );
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and for point out to me about the length checking, which slip my attention.